# Get Variables from Grep Output

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, grep, busybox

I am running a grep command and getting the output below:

```
user@hostname:~$ ps -o args | grep lp_ | grep -v grep | sort -n
/usr/local/bin/lp_server -n 5964 -d /dev/usb/lp1
/usr/local/bin/lp_server -n 5965 -d /dev/usb/lp0
{lp_supervisor} /bin/sh /usr/local/lp/lp_supervisor /dev/usb/lp0 SAMPLESERIAL1 /var/run/lp/lp_pid/usb_lp0
{lp_supervisor} /bin/sh /usr/local/lp/lp_supervisor /dev/usb/lp1 SAMPLESERIAL2 /var/run/lp/lp_pid/usb_lp1
```

The end goal is to have `SAMPLESERIAL1` (3rd line) assigned with port `5964` and `SAMPLESERIAL2` (4th line) assigned with port `5965` (there are time when these ports get flipped as you can see above)

I need to check which `/dev/usb/lp#` is assigned to which port.

Then check which `/dev/usb/lp#` is assigned to which `SAMPLESERIAL#`

Eventually I'll have something like:

```
if SAMPLESERIAL1 is set to 5964:
    do nothing
else:
    run command to change
```

I'm not sure the best way to go about this. I'm not too experienced with bash. My original thought was to try and parse the output into variables, but there may be a more efficient way to do this. I'm running this on tinycore linux if that helps at all.
.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to launch the `lp_server` correctly from the start?

Answer (score 0):

You could use advanced regex (positive look behind/ahead) :

```
SAMPLESERIAL1=$(ps -o args | grep -Po '(?<=lp_server -n )[[:digit:]]+(?= -d \/dev\/usb\/lp1)')
```